Unable to Connect Firebase To FlutterFlow
I am Making a app with FlutterFlow but when i connect my  Firebase id to FlutterFlow it can't connect it shows "Project id must be hyphens and alphanumeric"
I log in to flutterflow and firebase by other accounts but problem is same

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

give flutterflow permission as editor, in your firebase project "firebase@flutterflow.io"

no , I work according to your answer but it can't help me

when you copy and paste the id just make sure there is no space before the id

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
